# Check the 3 first characters of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given '052....', I need to check that the first two characters are '05' and the 3rd is between 0 and 9 but not 1. 
I have tried:

```
var regex = /^[05]+[0,2-9]/;
```

Comment: `[05]+` is means 1-or-more-of-these-chars. 000000005555050505050505050505 would match. Try `[05]{2}` instead...

Comment: Where does this frequent mistake of putting `[ ]` around strings come from?

Comment: @Barmar I guess there's some part of the syntax that OP didn't get

Comment: it's not a mistake, partially. op needs to match two particular characters in two particular positions. so `[05]` gives those chars, but the mistake is using `+` instead of `{2}`.

Comment: @MarcB I understood the order of those characters was important

Comment: @dystroy It's not just this OP, it happens all the time.

Comment: @dystroy: ah yes, I guess it can be read that way...

Comment: @Barmar Look at your average computer language, what do you have ? Braces, spaces, semicolons, comas everywhere. Most developers are so used to verbosity they expect it in any grammar. No wonder a developer is surprised at first that there is no separator in a character class for example.

Comment: @dystroy What separator are you talking about? My question is why so many people think they need to write `[05]` instead of just `05`.

Comment: That's just another example of unexpected conciseness. OP expected both delimiters around 05 and a separator between 0 and 2-9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost there :

```
var regex = /^05[02-9]/;
```

Comment: As this is basic enough I hope it's self explanatory but don't hesitate to ask a question if some part is unclear.